# something olike the multi desktops app

Tags: android

any idea how to implement something like the multiple desktops of the android?

I tried Gallery but it sucks I wansted something just like the desktop app

thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `<ScrollView>`?  I've never tried this so i dont know if its possible, but you might try sticking some layouts in a ScrollView and then listen for the scroll event.  When the scroll event happens, you can then automatically scroll them from 1 view to the other so that they never end up half way between one or the other...  if you try this, please post the code, i'd be interested in seeing how you do it...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used this tutorial :
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It works very well but there is still the large background image sliding a bit at each page change to do.